# SQL Divided by Zero error and Syntax error in Case statement

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm generating a report in SQL. I had an error of divided by zero. To resolve this error, I used case in SQL query. Now I'm getting a syntax error at 'as'. Is there anyone who can help me to resolve this issue?

```
create procedure dbo.CompanyAverageSales @startdate as varchar(50),@enddate 
as varchar(50)
As begin

select  datename(year,SO_SalesOrder.InvoicedDate) as [Year],
    datename(month,SO_SalesOrder.InvoicedDate) as [Month],
    l.Name as [Store Name], 
    case when sum(convert(int,SO_SalesOrder.Custom1))>0 then sum(SO_SalesOrder_Line.SubTotal)/sum(convert(int,SO_SalesOrder.Custom1)) as [Average Sales]
From SO_SalesOrder
inner join BASE_Location l on SO_SalesOrder.LocationId = l.LocationId 
inner join SO_SalesOrder_Line
on SO_SalesOrder.SalesOrderId = SO_SalesOrder_Line.SalesOrderId
inner join BASE_PaymentTerms
on BASE_PaymentTerms.PaymentTermsId = SO_SalesOrder.PaymentTermsId
where SO_SalesOrder.InvoicedDate >= @startdate and SO_SalesOrder.InvoicedDate <= @enddate
group by l.Name,
         datename(year,SO_SalesOrder.InvoicedDate),
         datename(month,SO_SalesOrder.InvoicedDate)


end
```

Comment: `CASE WHEN THEN [ELSE] END`

Comment: @IvanStarostin thanks for help. It's working now. But how to name that column? Because when I use 'as [Average Sales]', it gives me error

Comment: Which error? How does your code look like now?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add `END` before `AS`

```
case 
when sum(convert(int,SO_SalesOrder.Custom1))>0 
then 
    sum(SO_SalesOrder_Line.SubTotal)/sum(convert(int,SO_SalesOrder.Custom1)) 
Else 
    0
END as [Average Sales]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
case when sum(convert(int,SO_SalesOrder.Custom1))>0 then 
sum(SO_SalesOrder_Line.SubTotal)/sum(convert(int,SO_SalesOrder.Custom1)) as 
[Average Sales
```

Should be:

```
 case when sum(convert(int,SO_SalesOrder.Custom1))>0 then 
 sum(SO_SalesOrder_Line.SubTotal)/sum(convert(int,SO_SalesOrder.Custom1)) 
 ELSE 0 -- your logic here
 END as [Average Sales
```

Answer (score 2):

A nice way to avoid division by zero in this case is to use `NULLIF`:

```
sum(SO_SalesOrder_Line.SubTotal) 
/ 
NULLIF(sum(convert(int,SO_SalesOrder.Custom1)), 0)
```

This will return `NULL` if `sum(convert(int,SO_SalesOrder.Custom1)) = 0`

If you want to return `0` then you can wrap the expression in a `COALESCE`:

```
COALESCE(sum(SO_SalesOrder_Line.SubTotal) 
         / 
         NULLIF(sum(convert(int,SO_SalesOrder.Custom1)), 0), 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select
    sum(SO_SalesOrder_Line.SubTotal)/NULLIF(sum(convert(int,SO_SalesOrder.Custom1)),0)
FROM ...
```

This will returns Null for records with result with Devided by zero

Answer (score 0):

This line generates error:

```
case when sum(convert(int,SO_SalesOrder.Custom1))>0 then sum(SO_SalesOrder_Line.SubTotal)/sum(convert(int,SO_SalesOrder.Custom1)) as [Average Sales]
```

You should close `case` statement with `end`:

```
case when sum(convert(int,SO_SalesOrder.Custom1))>0 then sum(SO_SalesOrder_Line.SubTotal)/sum(convert(int,SO_SalesOrder.Custom1)) end as [Average Sales]
```